# AWS Elastic Container Service (ECS) Auto Scaling is not creating new instances when required

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr, aws-auto-scaling

I am trying to create an application where every time user clicks a button, I create a task on ECS. The problem is when the CPU is fully utilized in an ECS cluster, the auto-scaling group is not spinning up more EC2 instances in that cluster. Thus, my task creation request fails with the error: RESOURCE: CPU.

Parameters I am using:

```
ECSTaskCpu:
   Type: Number
   Default: 1024

ECSTaskMemory:
    Type: Number
    Default: 1970

ECSContainerCpu:
    Type: Number
    Default: 1024

ECSContainerMemory:
    Type: Number
    Default: 1970

ECSContainerMemoryReservation:
    Type: Number
    Default: 1970
```

InstanceType: t2.small

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: here is step by step guide to achieve the auto scaling feature, please go through the doc hope it will help you.   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-configure-auto-scaling.html

Comment: Thanks a lot @MrOverflow for the help.